# Sympy Custom Discrete Random Variable

Tags: python, sympy

I want to have a custom discrete random variable in `sympy`. I'm aware of `sympy.stats.FiniteRV`, but I believe this requires you to define what the probability mass function is; I need a symbolic discrete RV. I don't know of any way in `sympy.stats` to define this, so currently I'm doing something like

```
from sympy import Function, Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
p = Function('p_x', nargs=1)
p_x = p(x)
```

to get my distribution. What I'd like, though, is for this function to be aware that it's a discrete probability distribution, that is, I want `p(x) >= 0` for all `x` and for the distribution to sum to one. The set that `p` is defined for is symbolic, but it'd be nice to be able to do something like

```
from sympy import symbols, Sum
x0, xm = symbols('x_0 x_m')
total_probability = Sum(p_x, (x, x0, xm)).doit()
assert total_probability == 1
```

where `p` is defined for the set `{x0, ...., xm}`.

Is there a way that I can subclass `Function` or something from `sympy.stats` to create a distribution where I pass in its support set and then it will properly sum to 1 and be non-negative over that set?

Bonus points - is there a way that this could also handle marginalization? I.e. if I have

```
pxy = Function('p_{x, y}', nargs=2)
py = Function('p_y', nargs=1)
y, y0, ym = symbols('y y_0 y_m')
# and somehow define the sets for these as x0, ..., xm and y0, ..., yn
Sum(pxy(x, y), (y, y0, ym)).doit() == p_x
```